# Add pagination and count of records in footer of asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset, footer

I have an asp.net grid view. I have already implemented pagination (page 12345678910....) where you click on page number and it takes you to that page.

I want to add a functionality in the same row as of pagination which shows "Showing 210 records". That is, which shows the total count of records currently showing in the grid.

Any pointers ? I want page numbers and the text message to be shown in same footer row.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagecount%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

You will need to provide a custom `<pagertemplate>` where you will insert a custom label, lets say `totalRecordCount`. Then in your code behind, you will need to get the total row count of your data using LINQ or any other method you like and assign it to the custom label text.

I hope this helps.

Comment: The Pager template gives a different row. I want everything in one single row.

Comment: In any normal grid if you give a footer and pager template, it will come in two different rows.

Comment: In that case, you may need to roll out your own custom pager template to accommodate for your needs. I don't think that the built-in control can provide you what you need.